# wordpress custom theme posttype from dashboard appearance issue

Tags: html, wordpress, themes, dashboard, appearance

I made a static html page and i wanted to run this page using wordpress locally (wamp).I put all the necessary files to wp_content->themes->theme folder name ,such as footer.php index.php header.php functions.php style.css and made one page template called custompage.php and one page-about-us.php.I have made my pages from wordpress dashboard and i mannually made navigation menus  by adding some code to functions.php and loaded three theme locations to wordpress appearance->menus->menu settings.My links to my pages seem to work fine but my problem is when i click to a page for example page-about-us.php doesnt display the content from edit pages wordpress dashboard but display what i code in my page-about-us.php file.In other words I want when i link to a page display the content i write in  wordpress edit page.I suppose this is done with functions.Which functions or what to do for fix this?Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to retrieve data from the page about-us wordpress admin dashboard i only had to code while(have_posts()) : the_post();
         the_content();
   endwhile; inside the page-about-us.php file